# Any pointers on setting up Chef Push Jobs Client on macOS 10.13?

Tags: macos, chef-infra, macos-high-sierra, chef-solo, cookbook

I am trying to set up chef-push-jobs client on a macOS 10.13 node.

Here is what I did so far:

- Installed push-jobs-client for macOS from [Chef Downloads](https://downloads.chef.io/push-jobs-client/stable/2.4.8)
- Created a configuration file named push-jobs-client.rb that looks something like this:

  ```
  chef_server_url   'https://chef.XXXXX.com/organizations/XXXXX'
  node_name         'default-macos-1013'
  client_key        '/opt/chef/embedded/ssl/cert.pem'
  trusted_certs_dir '/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.8.5/spec/data/trusted_certs'
  verify_api_cert   true
  ssl_verify_mode   :verify_peer
  allow_unencrypted true
  log_level         :info
  log_location      STDOUT

  whitelist({"chef-client"=>"chef-client"})

  Mixlib::Log::Formatter.show_time = false
  ```
- Ran this command:

  ```
  /usr/local/bin/pushy-client -c push-jobs-client.rb
  ```

Error Message:

> /opt/push-jobs-client/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/opscode-pushy-client-2.4.8/lib/pushy_client.rb:236:in
>   `rescue in get_config': Could not download push jobs config
>   (RuntimeError)

Log:

```
INFO: [jenkins03] Setting reconfigure deadline to 2018-05-04 12:05:31
+0200
INFO: [jenkins03] using config file path: '/opt/push-jobs-client/push-jobs-client.rb'
INFO: [jenkins03] Using node name: jenkins03 
INFO: [jenkins03] Using org name: XXXXX 
INFO: [jenkins03] Using Chef server: https://chef.XXXXX.com/organizations/XXXXX 
INFO: [jenkins03] Using private key: /opt/chef/embedded/ssl/cert.pem 
INFO: [jenkins03] Incarnation ID: 633f168d-c8c0-469e-a9c0-8d6658b3b3d5 
INFO: [jenkins03] Allowing fallback to unencrypted connection: true 
INFO: [jenkins03] Starting client ... 
INFO: [jenkins03] Retrieving configuration from https://chef.XXXXX.com/organizations/XXXXX//pushy/config/jenkins03: ... 
INFO: Could not download push jobs config
```

So it looks like the connection and the authentication is successful but for some reason push-jobs-client cannot retrieve the configuration from the server.

I tried to go the URL from the log manually in a browser directly on the node and I see this in the browser window:

```
{"error":["missing required authentication header(s) 'X-Ops-UserId', 'X-Ops-Timestamp', 'X-Ops-Sign', 'X-Ops-Content-Hash'"]}
```

So I wonder if I did anything wrong in the configuration? Or maybe it is a bug in the push-jobs-client for macOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the client_key at /opt/chef/embedded/ssl/cert.pem was not a cient_key signed by the chef server. The correct client key was found at /etc/chef/client.pem

Now everything works, but I will leave the answer here in case anyone else has a similar issue.